# ng2-smart-table how to have edit popup

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

[image: a busy cat]

Currently, when I click edit on my ng2-table, I get an inline editing option.

[image: a busy cat]

However, what I want to happen, is have a popup editable box (Example image is for add, but it would be the same for edit with just prefilled data and a different title)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

add the "mode: 'external'" to your settings object

HTML:

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" (edit)="editRow($event)">
```

settings object:

```
settings = {
    mode: 'external',
    edit: {
        editButtonContent: 'string_or_html'
    }
    columns: {...}
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
editRow(event) {
    console.log('event: ', event)
}
```

Comment: you need to add modal or dialog and pass the event data into that popup